# Scala XML pattern with whitespace

Tags: xml, scala, pattern-matching

Is there a value of `xml` which will match the following pattern?

```
xml match { case <foo> { x } </foo> => 42 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

```
scala> val x = 33
x: Int = 33

scala> val xml = <foo> { x } </foo>
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <foo> 33 </foo>

scala> xml match { case <foo> { x } </foo> => 42 }
res0: Int = 42
```

I think where your confusion comes in is it doesn't match against `<foo> 33 </foo>`

```
scala> <foo> 33 </foo> match { case <foo> { x } </foo> => 42 }
scala.MatchError: <foo> 33 </foo> (of class scala.xml.Elem)
```

This is because when you use the `{}`, scala inserts extra elements for the spaces before and after the `{}`, so you get three elements, not one. You can see this by calling `unapplySeq` (which is what is used for the pattern matching):

```
scala> scala.xml.Elem.unapplySeq(<foo> 33 </foo>)
res4: Option[(String, String, scala.xml.MetaData, scala.xml.NamespaceBinding, Seq[scala.xml.Node])] =
    Some((null,foo,,,ArrayBuffer( 33 )))

scala> scala.xml.Elem.unapplySeq(<foo> { x } </foo>)
res5: Option[(String, String, scala.xml.MetaData, scala.xml.NamespaceBinding, Seq[scala.xml.Node])] =
    Some((null,foo,,,ArrayBuffer( , 33,  )))
```

Notice in the second example, you're getting three elements in the ArrayBuffer, and only one in the first. So the pattern doesn't match correctly.

Comment: Righty, thanks! It's also very handy to know about Elem.unapplySeq.